# angularjs routing - stay on page and do nothing on "otherwise" method

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I need to set Angularjs routing to do nothing on "otherwise" method.

```
var townApp = angular.module('townApp', ["ngRoute"]);
townApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/dashboard", {
            templateUrl : "/profile/dashboard/"
        })
        .when("/payments", {
            templateUrl : "/profile/payments/",
        })
        .otherwise(
            /* DO NOTHING.*/
        )
});
```

Right now, it cleans the ng-view directive upon changing url to an undefined one and that's not what I need. 
How can I make it stay on the same page and do nothing?

Comment: removing `otherwise` would work I guess..

Comment: @PankajParkar I have a dropdown menu item wich contains an <a href="#">, and by clicking on that my contents will be cleaned until I click on a submenu with a defined route. removing otherwise did not fix it.

Comment: just have `href=""` instead of `href="#"`

Comment: still the same. i will update the question and add a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ILCVkughMS4).
I have no idea what is happening but it works as i want.

```
townApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/dashboard", {
            templateUrl : "/profile/dashboard/"
        })
        .when("/payments", {
            templateUrl : "/profile/payments/",
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: $routeProvider});
});
```